# How to include change_view form with value

Tags: python, django

I have `Book` table there only one filed `value` contains encrypted `title` and `descriptions` of the books.

Now  i am doing admin function there admin can view or edit user's submitted title and descriptions.

so far i drive to get value field in `admin/users/book/5/` using the custom `ModelForm`
And here i just want to show user's submitted `value` using `extra_context` but you know what that's not showing anything in the field.

*models.py*

```
class Book(models.Model):
    values = models.CharField(max_length=800, null=True, blank=True)
```

*forms.py*

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField()
    def save(self, commit=True):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get('value', None)
    class Meta:
        Model = Book
```

*admin.py*

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
            return super(BookAdmin, self).add_view(request)
        def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='',):
            bookInfo = Book.objects.get(pk=object_id)
            pprint.pprint(bookInfo.values)
            extra_context = {}
            extra_context['value'] = bookInfo.values
            pprint.pprint(extra_context)
            return super(BookAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
    form = BookForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('value',),
        }),
    )
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Here they are mention [changelist_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view) . I tried that too but i don't know how to include the extra_context in `book_change_form.html`

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: @DanielRoseman if i correct it gives me indentation problem the way i show to you that's working( anyway) what about my issue ? did you got my point .. ? currently the field is empty i just want to fill with desire data .. ! how to do that .. ? can you point me ?

Comment: No, not until you fix your indentation, because it's impossible to tell what's going on. Please show your code here **exactly** as you are running it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I included my forms and admin.py files. Can you point me now .. ?

Comment: @em___life  Get `title` and `des..` from `values` field and show that into custom `ModelForm` in admin. .! is that you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the word is **`Providing initial values for custom fields based on instance data`**

include below code in your forms.py then it will work ....

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):            
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    if instance:
        pprint.pprint(instance.values)
        self.base_fields['values'].initial = instance.values
    forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```